# A better way to extract all archives into their own folders in a single line in UNIX

Tags: unix, sh

I've already accomplished this task in a way I'm not satisfied with:

```
for i in *.*; do mkdir "${i}"_; 7za x "${i}" -o"${i}"_; done
```

There has to be a better way to do this, right? If so, what is it?
Parameters of success:

- Must be a single line
- Must be non-interactive
- Must extract all archives into their own folders

Thanks!

Comment: What are you not satisfied with?

Comment: The underscore after the folder name. When I tried omitting it, and I got an error. I think it had to do with the archives being the same name. Am I wrong, and my error was something else that was fixed by my fiddling?

Comment: Well, you can't have two files with the same name in the same directory.

Comment: That's interesting - even if one is a directory? In Windows, this is not the case. Of course, Windows and UNIX are different. I guess I didn't know of this difference as well.

Comment: You can't have that in Windows either. If you think you have a file and a directory in the same place with the same name, you've been misled by a file manager that is hiding part of the filename (i.e. the directory is called `foo` and the file is called `foo.zip` but the file manager hides the `.zip` from you).